# Is it possible to view our flag weights?

Tags: support

Where can I view my flag weight? I want to make sure that I am flagging correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Look in your user profile, under your gravatar.

[image]

Note that the flag weight is *not* displayed if it's exactly `100` (default).

Comment: Is this still correct? Or is my flag weight exactly 100?

Comment: @Andrew this is indeed outdated. Flag weight is still calculated internally, but is no longer displayed, in favor of the number of helful flags.